# How do I display result on the same page if I meet condition in php?

Tags: php, forms

I want to display a checkbox on the same page if the second option is chosen, could you help me with the code please.

Here is my current code:

```
<form action="form1.php" method="post">
<?php

$company = array (1 => 'One', 'Two', 'Three');
echo '<fieldset>
<select name="companys">';
foreach ($company as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>\n";
}
echo '</select>';
if ($company == 2) {
    echo'<p><input type="checkbox" name="tandc" value="terms" />I accept the terms and conditions
    </p>';
} else {
    echo 'OK';
};
echo '</fieldset>';
?>
</form>
```

Comment: try returning false at the end of your php/js code to prevent the form from getting submitted

Comment: How are you determining if the second option is chosen? I dont think you need \n after each option. Also if you want it to be done dynamically from the select then you need to use javascript

Comment: I am trying to use javascript shown below but checkbox doesn't appear...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you post the form somewhere, and the current page is form1.php.

```
<form action="form1.php" method="post">
<?php

$company = array(1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two', 3 => 'Three');
echo '<fieldset>
    <select name="companys">';

        foreach ($company as $key => $value) {
            echo "<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>\n";
        }

echo '</select>';

if (isset($_POST['companys']) && $_POST['companys'] == 2) {
    echo'<p><input type="checkbox" name="tandc" value="terms" />I accept the terms and conditions</p>';
} else {
    echo 'OK';
}

echo '</fieldset>';

?>
</form>
```

Comment: Pretty much. The (probably better) alternative would be to use javascript.

Comment: @VladPreda What you think about my approach?

Comment: I don't want to post it anywhere, I want that checkbox appear on current page (form1.php). And unfortunately in my case this is not working...

Comment: You always want to show it? Why not just remove the `if` condition or switch the `if` and `else` conditions around?

Comment: No, I want that checkbox with text appear only when the second option is chosen without submitting. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you would have to use JavaScript instead of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
***if ($company == 2) {***
```

$company is defined as array but you have mentioned as string. please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<?php

$company = array (1 => 'One', 'Two', 'Three');
echo '<fieldset>
<select name="companys">';
foreach ($company as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value=\"$key\" onclick='this.form.submit()'>$value</option>\n";
}
echo '</select>';
if ($_POST['companys'] == 2) {
    echo'<p><input type="checkbox" name="tandc" value="terms" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>I accept the terms and conditions
 </p>';
} else {
    echo 'OK';
};
echo '</fieldset>';
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not working as well, I got error message - Notice: Undefined index: companys

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to submit form to just show an element if dropdown value matches condition you  can simply use javascript function to make it possible see example code below

```
<form action="form1.php" method="post">
    <?php

    $company = array(1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two', 3 => 'Three');
    echo '<fieldset>
        <select name="companys" onchange="check_option(this.value);">';

            foreach ($company as $key => $value) {
                echo "<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>\n";
            }

    echo '</select>';


    echo'<p><input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="tandc" value="terms"  style="display:none;"/>I accept the terms and conditions</p>';


    echo '</fieldset>';

    ?>
    </form>
    <script>
        function check_option(val)
        {
            if(val=='Two')
            {
                document.getElementById('terms').style.display='block';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I want that checkbox with text appear just below the options menu on current page as I chose option number 2... is that possible? In your example i just see the "I accept..." text instead of 'Ok' and no matter what option I chose.

Comment: It will just show below select only.I have modified the array also please refer that also  and the style in the checkbox also.

Comment: I copied this code, but unfortunately the checkbox stay invisible at any option I chose.